# Have you seen this user?

Tags: discussion

One of the most infamous users on the Stack Exchange network has been moved to the top of the Christianity Stack Exchange most wanted list.

### fredsbend - Christianity Stack Exchange's Most Wanted User

[image: fredsbend natural]

As a result of the effort to apprehend this user he has gone into hiding, but reports of suspicious looking characters have been made. He may appear in some of these disguises.

### Aliases and Disguises of user fredsbend

[image: Aliases and Disguises of user fredsbend]

The other users on the list remain just as wanted:

### Christianity Stack Exchange Most Wanted List

[image: Christianity Stack Exchange Most Wanted List]

Our only current lead in apprehending these animals is the code name "winter bash". Winter bash is either a hideout location or the sole supplier of these disguises.

These users are extremely dangerous. Approach them with caution. They have been known to provide answers that will blow your mind and questions that will kill your ability to think. They also tend to support SE with a fanaticism that makes the most radical militants wane in comparison. There really is no telling what they might do.

**Please report any information you may have on the whereabouts of these users. Please also report any suspecious characters that you think might be connected to the code name "winter bash".**

---

UPDATE:

It seems that there is a likelihood that the user fredsbend has now become the leader of a large Methamphetamine manufacturing operation in New Mexico. Authorities are now looking into this possibility. fredsbend is now considered extremely dangerous. Do not approach this user if you see him in person.

[image: Breaking Bad]

Comment: I like the `fun` tag

Comment: @LCIII Yeah, I figured it's good to build site culture and post fun things every now and then on meta. Considering the looser guidelines on the meta site I figured most people would be okay with it. Just don't abuse it.

Comment: I'm all for an `abuse-of-fun` tag

Comment: This user looks suspicious http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/users/3961/fredsbend-the-grinch :)

Comment: @Belinda Indeed.